# Azure: Start large app quickly on demand?

Tags: azure

I don't really understand how cloud services work.
Especially I would like to know if its possible to:

Upload a big application (>1GB) one time only and pay little (only for the storage) and on demand, quickly spawn instances of it (with max. a few minutes of startup time).
So, only pay if the application really runs and not having to upload it all again every stop/start.

Thanks!
Greets,
soacc32

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to do so. In fact this is how cloud service deployment works. When you deploy your application from your local computer, first the application package files are uploaded in blob storage and then deployed from there. You could upload the package separately in blob storage and when you want to create the deployment, you just specify the blob URL. So if you're creating a deployment using the portal, for package file and configuration file location you would choose "FROM STORAGE" instead of "FROM LOCAL" as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ohh yea, thanks, I missed that.

Another question, do you know how long it takes for ~1GB to deploy from storage? Does it vary a lot?

Also, is it possible then to deploy to different regions or to have several instances running in different regions?

Comment: I was just trying out this http://blog.smarx.com/posts/tutorial-running-the-mongoose-web-server-in-windows-azure

And I got the following message:
"This deployment is stopped and is not accepting service requests. You will continue to incur compute charges until the deployment is deleted.
2 Instances: 2 Stopped"

Uhh, so its true that I have to pay computing costs even if the app isnt running?

Comment: That's correct. The reason for this is that Windows Azure has commissioned some resources (read Virtual Machines) for you and you pay for those resources. So if you know that your application is not going to get any hits, you may want to delete those deployments to stop incurring charges.

Comment: Regarding your 1st comment, honestly I don't know how much time Windows Azure would take deploying 1 GB from storage. Assuming that your cloud service and storage account are in the same region, usually accessing the blob storage would be very fast. However you may want to think about the package size. 1 GB package size is quite big and I think the maximum package size allowed is about 600 MB. If there's some static content in your app. you may want to save it in blob storage instead of bundling it with your package.

Comment: Ok thank you. Sadly, cloud services is not an option for me anymore.

Comment: Do take a look at Windows Azure Websites (https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/). I believe this is of some use to you.